# Passing URL to parse in Scrapy Spider URL is captured using Scrapy-Selenium

Tags: python, ajax, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website which has some dropdowns, So I planned to use Scrapy Framework with Scrapy-Selenium([more here](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium)) to click around the dropdowns(Nested For loop) and then capture the URL using below code and pass it to the parse() function to look for the needed data and scrape it to MySQL Database.

```
 now_url=self.driver.current_url

 print('Current URL is:'+now_url)
 yield Request(now_url,callback=self.parse)
            

def parse(self, response):
    
#This Function Will Loop though Each Page and Capture the Data Sets Available on Each Page of Medicine

# creating items to be stored in itemspy file with this Crawler: 

items=GrxItem()

#loop around the items on each medicine page(from a-z) and add them to items and throw into pipelines to SQL DB
```

But the logics seems not working as expected. Any insight to deal with this is appriciated. **[The full code is here](https://pastebin.com/LJPS7QVb)**.

EDIT:
I tried using SeleniumRequest() as well but it seems that too is not working.

Comment: Welcome to SO! The code sample you posted is very minimalistic and therefore not suitable for reproducing your issue. By the way, Scrapy-Selenium requires you to use `SeleniumRequest` or the middleware (which you have hopefully enabled in your settings.py or in your spiders `custom_settings`) will ignore your request.

Comment: Thanks for welcoming,  okay I will edit the code, and yes I added the middleware in settings.py

Comment: @PatrickKlein I have added pastebin link for full code of my spider.